# Javascript call inside Laravel Translation file

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.8

Laravel 5.8 with translation files. I need to call a Javascript function from inside a translation file. My initial approach was to call it like this:

```
'mentioned you in a <a href="javascript:postinfo(:post);">comment</a>'
```

This is the call from my blade file:

```
{!! __('notifications.mentionTimelinePost', ['post' => $mention->data['post']]) !!}
```

I will actually need it inside that translation file because of the wording and placement in different languages. I know that Laravel uses the `:value` syntax for variables from the Blade file, thats the reason why `javascript:postinfo` does not work, obviously. I tried escaping it but without success.

How could I make this work? The docs do not cover such a case.

This is how the above link gets rendered:

[image]

**Update:** I realised that I just have to rename the variable I'm giving to the translation file (or could have renamed the function name). ._. Case closed.

This worked just fine: `{!! __('notifications.mentionTimelinePost', ['postid' => $mention->data['post']]) !!}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually divide html tags and translated content.

```
{{ __('notifications.mentionTimelinePost'}}<a href="javascript:postinfo(:post);">{{$mention->data['post']}}</a>
```

If you are usually use it, just create view component.
Call it whatever you want (mention.blade.php).

`<span>
{{ __('notifications.mentionTimelinePost'}}<a href="javascript:postinfo(:post);">{{$post}}</a>
</span>`

and then just include in you blade file.

```
@include('mention.blade.php', ['post' => $post])
```

if I use:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething()">Click me</a>
```

script:

```
function doSomething() {alert("hello")}
```

it works in blade without any problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my case. I added a screenshot that shows the rendered link. Please note that I'm linking a word which can be *anywhere* in the sentence, thus your mentioned method can not work.